# Toolbar config doesn't work with inline CKEditor

Tags: javascript, ckeditor, ckeditor4.x

I try to apply a very simple toolbar config to an inline CKEditor. The goal is to only show a Bold button, but it doesn't work. Why?

```
CKEDITOR.inline(el.get(0),
{
  toolbar:
  [
     { name: 'basicstyles', items: [ 'Bold' ] }
  ]  
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/adrianrosca/q6x6s6ga/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've forked and updated your fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/Comandeer/q6x6s6ga/30/

```
$( function() {
    var el = $( '#editor1' );
    el.attr( 'contenteditable', true );

    CKEDITOR.inline( el.get( 0 ),
    {
        toolbar: [ [ 'Bold' ] ]
    } );
} );
```

There were two problems with your code:

1. You did not take into account fact that CKEditor automatically converts all `[contenteditable=true]` elements into its instances and you must [disable it first](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR-cfg-disableAutoInline). Therefore it's easier to add `[contenteditable]` right in your JS code and then create an inline editor.
2. Your syntax for the toolbar was wrong. [The configuration option](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.config-cfg-toolbar) takes array or string as a parameter – not object.

Edit: version with `CKEDITOR.disableAutoInline` https://jsfiddle.net/Comandeer/q6x6s6ga/31/

The problem was in waiting for `onload` event. If you just put that code on the end of `body`, everything is working fine.

Comment: The config can be set with `CKEDITOR.disableAutoInline = true;` like Matt describes in his answer. Can you make your fiddle working with that instead of adding the contenteditable attribute with jquery? I tried, but couldn't make it work...

Answer (score 0):

You can solve updating the CKEDITOR source, i.e.

http://cdn.ckeditor.com/4.5.7/standard/ckeditor.js

And editing your code as follows:

```
$(function()
 {
     var el = $("div");
     CKEDITOR.disableAutoInline = true;

  for (var inst in CKEDITOR.instances) {
     CKEDITOR.instances[inst].destroy();
   }

  CKEDITOR.inline(el.get(0),
  {
    toolbar:
    [
        { name: 'basicstyles', items: [ 'Bold' ] }
    ]  
  });
});
```